# Save tableViewCell in an array, Cache UITableViewCell in an array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, preload, prepareforreuse

I am developing a tableView where each cell consists of AVPlayer and has the height of view.frame.size.height and paging is also enabled. so essentially it will work similar to tiktok application feed. The problem I am having is that I've to destroy AVPlayer in prepareForReuse to show new video when a cellForRow is called otherwise if I don't destroy it and user scroll fast, the older video appear for a second and if I destroy player each time before using then AVPlayer takes a second to load and in between show black screen. It works but the result is not elegant.

So is there any way I can preload cells and save them in an array. Like an array which will consist of three independent cells. and we can change the value in them when a user scroll

For example

```
[] represents cell on screen

0 [1] 2

array[1] would always be the cell on screen 
array[0] previous
array[2] next

if user scroll down then
array[0] = array[1]
array[1] = array[2] 
array[2] = create next one (proactively)

if user scroll up then
let array1 = array[1]
array[1] = array[0]
array[0] = array1
array[2] = create new one
```

Comment: Have you looked at [prefetching](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching)

Comment: @RobertCrabtree Yeah but it is good for network calls right not for cell creation.

Comment: Indeed, but it's hard to say what would help you without looking at your current code.

Comment: It sounds like your problem, basically, is that it takes too long to setup AVPlayer, probably (from the sound of it) due to a network request. Do this part in your prefetch so it is ready by the time your cell asks for it. Also, I would continue to clear up your cell in prepareForReuse.

Comment: @DPMitu already doing it, for further explanation the I am playing videos saved in phone's storage which is already downloaded. Still avplayer take a second to load it properly and become ready to play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem with tableView but was unable to do so. I ended up making a custom tableview with scrollview which have the similar implementation asked in the question. So it is doable with scrollview to preload cells. Code provided below is just for reference

```
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    //Condition for first cell
    if currentIndex == 0 && (scrollView.contentOffset.y > view.frame.minY) {
        //pageIndex will only be one if the user completly scrolls the page, if he scroll half a returns it will remain 0
        if pageIndex == 1 {
            //so if the user completely scroll to page 1 the change the previous index to 0
            //new current index will be 1
            //call scrollForward which will prepare the cell for index 2
            previousIndex = currentIndex
            currentIndex = Int(pageIndex)
            if shouldCallScrollMethods {
                scrollForward()
            }

            guard let currentCell = getCellOnScreen() else { return }
            currentCell.refreshBottomBarView()
        }
    //Condition for rest of the cells
    } else {
        //this condition checks if the user completly scroll to new page or just drag the scrollview a bit gets to old position
        if (pageIndex != currentIndex) {
            //Update the previous and current to new values
            previousIndex = currentIndex
            currentIndex = Int(pageIndex)
            //Checks if the user is scroll down the calls scrollForwad else scrollBackward
            if shouldCallScrollMethods {
                if currentIndex > previousIndex {
                   scrollForward()
                } else {
                   scrollBackward()
                }
            }
            guard let currentCell = getCellOnScreen() else { return }
            currentCell.refreshBottomBarView()
        }
    }
}

private func scrollForward() {
    //print("scrollForward")
    addCell(at: currentIndex + 1, url: getPlayerItem(index: currentIndex + 1))
    removeCell(at: currentIndex - 2)

}

private func scrollBackward() {
    //Condition to check if the element is not at 0
    //print("scrollBackward")
    addCell(at: currentIndex - 1, url: getPlayerItem(index: currentIndex - 1))
    removeCell(at: currentIndex + 2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a job for a collection view. You should be able to achieve the smooth loading you want by prefetching and populating the cell for display once the data is received.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching/prefetching_collection_view_data

> **Prefetching Collection View Data**
>
> *Load data for collection view cells before they are displayed.*
>
> A collection view displays an ordered collection of cells in
>   customizable layouts. The UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching
>   protocol helps provide a smoother user experience by prefetching the
>   data necessary for upcoming collection view cells. When you enable
>   prefetching, the collection view requests the data before it needs to
>   display the cell. When it’s time to display the cell, the data is
>   already locally cached.
>
> The image below shows cells outside the bounds of the collection view
>   that have been prefetched.

[image]

If this doesn't do what you are looking for, please post your code.

Comment: prefetching is also available for UITableViews but I think you haven't read the comments. I am already using the prefetching stuff but it is recommended for network calls not cell creation.

Comment: @HassanKhan, alright, I've read the comments on your original question that explain a bit more. Maybe check out UIPageViewController, because you can't really load cells the way you are suggesting in a table view. I'd really need to see the code to see how to optimize it.

Comment: @HassanKhan, I've never had trouble loading collection view cells with complex layouts (including media). I'm not trying to push a collection view on you, it's just what I have used for things like this since table views are really meant for basic layouts of, well, tables. Also, it is common practice to load a cover image before playing a video since sometimes this takes time to load/setup a video player (as you're experiencing).

Comment: I don't think the answer you have given is not relevant to the question. Because I tried collection view and it did not solve my problem. No offence intended.

Comment: @HassanKhan, ok, what about loading a cover image while you are setting up your AVPlayer as suggested? Again, I really need to see some code to better assist with this.

Comment: Loading image is a good idea, and it was the first thing that I thought when this issue occurred. But avPlayer by default loads first frame before it start playing the video.

Comment: Gotcha. Are you going to upload any code as per SO guidelines? "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask